# Bad Access using NSMutableArray with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocos2d-iphone

At the moment I am creating a game with cocos2d v3.1 using box2d, so I have to use .mm extensions for my source files to indicate that I am using c++.
The game contains an „endless terrain“ that consists of terrain-key-points.  I created a class that saves those key points named TerrainElement.
At the beginning of the game I create an NSMutableArray called _elements array and fill it with random TerrainElements.

Within the game loop I check I iterate over the elements, and draw all those elements that are now visible. However the App crashes after a rather random amount of time.

Header

```
@interface TerrainBase : CCNode{
     NSMutableArray * _elements;
}
```

part of the game loop:

```
while (((TerrainElement*)[_elements objectAtIndex:toKeyPoint]).startPoint.x < _currentX+winSize.width*9/8) {

    //Crashes sometimes here EXC_BAD_ACCESS, _elements array is NULL
     TerrainElement *element = (TerrainElement*)[_elements objectAtIndex:toKeyPoint];


    [element drawElement];
    toKeyPoint++;

}
```

I was not able to figure out why the NSMutableArray was NULL. I just iterate over the elements in each loop, and do not touch them basically. I made a property out of the _elements Array(nonatomic,strong), which did not help either.
I decided to use a normal array instead of the NSMutableArray. I did not change the code at all, except for the indexing of the array:

```
@interface TerrainBase : CCNode{
    TerrainElement *_elements[4000];
}
```

gameLoop:

```
while ( _elements[toKeyPoint].startPoint.x< _currentX+winSize.width*9/8) {

            [_elements[toKeyPoint] drawElement];

    toKeyPoint++;

}
```

This time everything works, and the array is never NULL. Its a mystery to me why the second solution works but the first keeps crashing. I would really prefer to use the NSMutableArray as it gives me more flexibility. 
Can anybody help?

Comment: Show the *complete* exception message and exception stack trace.

Comment: Down-voted for not having exception message and stack trace.

Comment: crashing after a "random" amount of time is indicative of a larger problem such as leaking memory to the point things explode.

Comment: Where and how do you assign _elements? Ie there should be at a minimum: _elements = [NSMutableArray array];   .. Also note that in the while loop you're accessing the same element twice, you may want to speed this up by assigning the current element before and in the loop so there's only one array access per enumeration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are allowed to send messages to `nil` (`NULL`) so that is not a reason to crash on its own (you would just get `nil` back in this case).

I'm not sure you have given enough information to determine an actual cause. Please post the stacktrace and any exceptions. does your posted code contain everything happening in that loop?

your loop condition looks like flawed logic to me in a couple of ways:

1. unless your array is sorted by `startPoint.x` you will stop drawing terrain as soon as you encounter the first element >= `_currentX+winSize.width*9/8`
2. as I stated above, you *can* send messages to `nil` and you will get `nil` (or `NULL` or `0` or whatever you want to call it) back for the value returned. This means that you have an infinite loop whenever `_elements` is `nil` (because `[_elements objectAtIndex:toKeyPoint]).startPoint.x` will always evaluate to `0` which is always < `_currentX+winSize.width*9/8` presumably.

I need more information to help you further.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I should not post after having drunk 3 beer :-/ 
Of course I am calling [element drawElement] in the approach that is not working. And the app crashes while getting the element of NSMutableArray at the desired index.

Comment: @Rambazamba -- Show the complete exception message and stack trace.

Comment: @Rambazamba updated answer, but still need more info.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay - the issue is really caused by a memory leak. Thx for pointing me to the right direction @ Brad Allred.  I will post the solution when I am back from holiday next week. Thx @ all for the help :-)